# How to check for existence of a facts CLIPS without seeing an error?

Tags: clips

My code might have facts such as:
`(assert (person "Jack")) (assert (fruit "apple"))`
I would like to print for example the person if only it exists such as
The person is "Jack"

I tried using this condition
`(if (find-fact ((?f person)) TRUE) then (printout t "The fact exists." crlf) )`
but if the person relation does not exist, it shows an error. I do not want to see anything or error if the fact does not exist. Is this possible
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the error you get is the following:

```
[PRNTUTIL1] Unable to find deftemplate 'person'.
```

The reason is you are using an ordered fact. Ordered facts do not have associated `deftemplates`, hence the error. CLIPS creates an implicit `deftemplate` whenever a new fact of a give type is created. This is why you see the `find-fact` function working if the `person` fact is asserted.

```
In [1]: (get-deftemplate-list)
()
In [2]: (assert (person "Jack"))
(person "Jack")
In [3]: (get-deftemplate-list)
('person',)
```

The best solution, would be to use `deftemplate` facts instead of ordered ones. In this way, the engine knows beforehand which types of fact exist and can use this information to build its internal queries.

```
In [1]: (deftemplate person
   ...:   (slot name))

In [2]: (get-deftemplate-list)
('person',)
In [3]: (find-fact ((?f person)) TRUE)
()
In [4]: (assert (person (name "Jack")))
(person (name "Jack"))
In [5]: (find-fact ((?f person)) TRUE)
(TemplateFact: (person (name "Jack")),)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It is really helpful.

Comment: Please mark the answer as solved if so. It helps other users which might encounter similar problems.